# How can I extract duplicate tuples within a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, duplicates, tuples

I am writing a program where I need to find same dates...

I currently store the dates on different lists for day and month and then `zip` them to a date list... so the date list might look something like this:

```
[(2,4),(4,18),(10,7)]
```

My problem is I need to extract the duplicate tuples to another list not just eliminate them with some `set()` or so.

If my date list gets `[(2,3),(2,3),(4,8)]` I need to get `(2,3)` to a new list.

Alternatively I could form the date list into a `dictionary` and then piece it again in items but I am asking if there is a simpler way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a counter for this task:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> L = [(2,3),(2,3),(4,8)]
>>> [k for k,count in Counter(L).items() if count > 1]
[(2, 3)]
```

If you want *all* the dupes, rather than one of each, then use the count as well as the key.

If you care about the original ordering, do the same thing but using an `OrderedCounter` instead:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): 
...     pass
```

Comment: I do not care about order so just the Counter will do it! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_list = [(2,3),(2,3),(4,8)]

>>> my_counter = Counter(my_list)
>>> [k for k, v in my_counter.items() if v>1]
[(2, 3)]
```

As an alternative, you may also get the desired result via using `set()` along with `list.count()` (Note: This method is less efficient):

```
>>> my_set = set(my_list)  # To get unique tuples
#            count of each tuple  v
>>> [t for t in my_set if my_list.count(t) > 1]
[(2, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.count()` to get the number of occurrences of each value in the list, and add them to a list if the value is `>1`:

```
[date for date in dates if dates.count(date)>1]
```

You can then use `set()` to remove duplicates from this, and convert it to a `list`:

```
new_list=list(set([date for date in dates if dates.count(date)>1]))
```

Output:

```
[(2,3)]
```

Comment: This code runs in quadratic time, so not an ideal solution I would say.